# What is the difference between maxSession and maxInstances when using Selenium Grid for parallel testing

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-grid

I am new to selenium grid. So can someone please explain me the difference between the `maxSession` and `maxInstances`. And also how many parallel browsers can be used in one node?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2#configuring-the-nodes) by default, starting a *Selenium Grid Node* allows for concurrent use of 11 browsers, comprising of **5** *Firefox*, **5** *Chrome* and **1** *Internet Explorer* browser.

The maximum number of concurrent tests is set to **5** by default. To change this configuration and other browser settings, you can pass in parameters to each `-browser` switch (each switch represents a node based on your parameters). If you use the `-browser` parameter, the default browsers will be ignored and only what you specify command line will be used.

---

### maxInstances

[maxInstances](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2#optional-parameters) is an optional parameter which can be passed through the `-browser` optional parameter. To configure a *Selenium Grid Node* for **20** instances of *Firefox version=X.Y.Z* you can use the following solution:

- Command:

  ```
  java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=geckodriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.1.125:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox,version=X.Y.Z,maxInstances=20,platform=WINDOWS
  ```
- Grid Console Snapshot:

[image: GidNodeFirefox20]

---

### -maxSession

[-maxSession](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2#optional-parameters) is also an optional parameter which can be passed through the `-browser` optional parameter to configure the maximum number of browsers that can run in parallel on the node. This is different from the `maxInstance` of supported browsers (Example: For a node that supporting Firefox version A.B.C, Firefox version P.Q.R  and Chrome version X.Y.Z, **maxSession=1** will ensure that you never have more than 1 browser running. With `maxSession=2` you can have 2 Firefox tests executing at the same time, or 1 Firefox and 1 Chrome test).

Example:

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=geckodriver.exe -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.1.125:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=firefox,version=A.B.C,maxInstances=10,platform=WINDOWS" -browser "browserName=firefox,version=P.Q.R,maxInstances=10,platform=WINDOWS" -browser "browserName=chrome,version=X.Y.Z,maxInstances=20,platform=WINDOWS" -maxSession 2
```

- Grid Console Snapshot:

[image: maxSession]