# Initiating 'print' on google chrome using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having a hard time initiating the 'print' event on google chrome using **selenium**.
I've tried all the following both on **OSX** and **Windows** with no luck. For OSX I've replaced `Keys.CONTROL` with `Keys.COMMAND`/`Keys.META`.

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://google.com")

# 1st try
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body'))
actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('p').key_up(Keys.CONTROL)
actions.perform()

# 2nd try
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('p').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()

# 3rd try
ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "p").perform()

# 4th try
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'p')
```

None of the above did the trick. The only method that worked is `driver.execute_script("window.print()")`, but that is not the behaviour I'm looking for in this case.

Chrome driver version 80.0.3987.106.

Any ideas? Is there a way to initiate the 'print' event without the use of hotkeys?

Comment: What do you mean window.print() is not hte behavior you're looking for? What is?

Comment: @DMart once window.print() is executed, the program will halt until the print window is closed. I need to access the DOM while the print dialog is open, but I can't do so.

Answer (score 0):

A few words:

- You [should not be testing print dialog](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/introduction/on_test_automation/) as it is a part of browser functionality and not related to your application.
- If your usecase is to test the browser but not the web application you should be aware that sticking to key events is not the best option to proceed as if/when you come to the situation of tests execution in [Selenium Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59647961/what-is-the-exact-purpose-of-selenium-grid/59648301#59648301) or any form of [Parallel Test Execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60204777/what-is-the-difference-between-maxsession-and-maxinstances-when-using-selenium-g/60226900#60226900) you may run intorace condition.

---

### Solution

So the way to go is `Window.print()` function instead and you can use either of the following strategies:

- Using [execute_script()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script):

  ```
  driver.execute_script("window.print()")
  ```
- Using [execute_async_script()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script):

  ```
  driver.execute_async_script("window.print()")
  ```

Comment: In the question... `The only method that worked is driver.execute_script("window.print()"), but that is not the behaviour I'm looking for in this case.`

Comment: As @JeffC mentioned, that is not the behaviour I'm looking for since once executed, the program will halt until the print window is closed. I need to access the DOM while the print dialog is open.